# Isolated storage File saving on the Default User Profile for a web service

Tags: asp.net, default, isolatedstorage

My problem is The following:

I have a windows application that stores a file on the current user's isolated storage, lets call this user Adam.

On the same machine I have a Web service (The Web Service's application pool is running with Adam's credentials) that uses the same dll to access the file on the isolated storage but it is trying to access a file on the Default User's profile instead of the real user's profile (in this case Adams Profile)

Why is it trying to look for the file on the Default User's profile Instead of Adam's Profile? How can i make it look for the file in the right profile?.

I'm running it on Win 2003, C# and .Net framework 3.5

Thanks.

Comment: I'm running this code on a different thread, if i run it on the main thread it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS i was runnig the code on a diferent thread, the credetials where not set for that thread, so all i have to do was to impersonate the main's thread identity and that works.
It should look like this

```
using (System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate())
     {
       //Consult the isolated storage here
     }
```

Comment: Huh, I've had a similar problem before, using threads in ASP.NET. Good solution -- I've never seen this use of "using" before.